# Was there any popular grievance, which affected people's daily lives, under the rule of Uthman?

Tags: history

I had the impression that Uthman was unpopular because he appointed his family members to positions of power. But a section in the wikipedia article about him gives the impression that the opposition to him was not purely political and people had dissatisfaction which they had not had during previous administrations.

> **Noting an increase in anti-government tension around the Caliphate,
>   Uthman's administration decided to determine its origins, extent, and
>   aims. Some time around 654, Uthman called all twelve provincial
>   governors to Medina to discuss the problem.** During this Council of
>   Governors, Uthman ordered that all resolutions of the council be
>   adopted according to local circumstances. Later, in the Majlis al
>   Shurah (council of ministers), it was suggested to Uthman that
>   reliable agents be sent to various provinces to attempted to determine
>   the source of the discontent. Uthman accordingly sent Muhammad ibn
>   Maslamah to Kufa, Usama ibn Zayd to Basra, Ammar ibn Yasir to Egypt,
>   and Abdullah ibn Umar to Syria. The agents sent to Kufa, Basra and
>   Syria reported that all was well--the people were generally satisfied
>   with the administration, although some individuals had minor personal
>   grievances. Ammar ibn Yasir, the emissary to Egypt, however, did not
>   return to Medina. Rebels there had been issuing propaganda in favour
>   of making Ali caliph. Ammar ibn Yasir, who had been affiliated with
>   Ali, abandoned Uthman for the Egyptian opposition. Abdullah ibn Saad,
>   the governor of Egypt, reported about the opposition's activities
>   instead. He wanted to take action against Ali's foster son, Muhammad
>   ibn Abi Bakr, Muhammad bin Abi Hudhaifa, Uthman's adopted son, and
>   Ammar ibn Yasir.
>
> Uthman's attempts to appease the dissidents In 655, **Uthman directed
>   those with any grievance against the administration, as well as the
>   governors and "Amils" throughout the caliphate, to assemble at Mecca
>   for the Hajj, promising that all legitimate grievances would be
>   redressed. Accordingly, large delegations from various cities came to
>   present their grievances before the gathering.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: "the people were generally satisfied with the administration, although some individuals had minor personal grievances" --- Your quoted text seems to suggest otherwise?!

Comment: @UmH "The agents sent to Kufa, Basra and Syria reported that--" I am looking for the historical consensus, not only the report of his agents to him

Comment: Yes, my question is what part of your quote gives you the impression that you ask about in the question.

Comment: @UmH I edited the question to reflect it

Comment: Well even if this might be a topic related to Islam my impression is that the question as is written is a better fit for [history SE](https://history.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Medi1Saif it’s about the political situation of Islam. He’s not just asking for a date of something, it’s very focused on Uthman, his decisions and the peoples mindset about him. Hence it belongs to here

Comment: @Honey that's your point of view I don't see any relevance to Islam but to the time of the caliphate of 'Othman so it certainly is a question on history. And politics are off-topic here.